# Cannot see the armature in edit mode

Tags: armature, edit-mode, visibility

So i was working on a model for my school project, and it was all going well until this happened. I can see the armature in object or pose mode, but if i switch to edit mode, the armature dissappears. I can still see the origin of the armature, and all the animations are still playable, there isnt anything wrong with the armature i think, but in no way you can edit the armature. I tried googling about this issue, but apparently no one had such problem like i am having right now.

The armature is not hidden in any way, maybe its a bug, i have know idea. I wish i had a copy of this model to which i can always go back, but i guess i learned my lesson this time.

Here is the armature in object mode where it is visible:[image]

Here is the armature in edit mode where it is not visible which is the reason why it cannot be edited, the origin point is still visible so i guess its still there.
[image]

I dont know how i got this problem, i was just working with the animations and was switching over to edit mode and couldn't see the armature anymore, very strange. If this problem persists i guess i'll just have to keep working on the model with the armature that i have lol.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks :)

Btw english isnt my best language so sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: May be the bones are hidden. Press alt+h.

Comment: Dude, honestly i didnt think it would work but it actually did. lol. i think i definitely tried alt-h, but dont understand why it didnt work then. anyway, thanks. i would never even think of alt-h but that just was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess what... im holding another Major L, @FFeller just told me the solution, i thought it wasnt gonna work cause i just did so much other stuff to figure this out so i didnt thought this small thing can be the fix, but it was. Just pressed Alt + H. Veeerry weird why it didnt work earlier before i posted this question, cause i obviously have tried pressing alt+h, or maybe thats what i think i did and its just me being dumb.